# error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined" when work with dynamic component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add the components dynamically in AngularCLi. I checked with other questions, But i cant find solution. I got the error.
If I add a button and access the function, components are added
**module.ts :**

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SpinnerComponent,
    ErrorPageComponent,
    DialogGridActionComponent,
    NotifierComponent,
    DynamicSelectedComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DynamicSelectedComponent
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule, FormsModule, MaterialModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  providers: [],
  exports: [HttpClientModule, MaterialModule, ReactiveFormsModule, SpinnerComponent],
})
```

**Component.ts:**

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'dialog-grid',
      templateUrl: './dialog-grid-action.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./dialog-grid-action.component.css']
    })
    export class DialogGridActionComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy , OnInit {
    
      @ViewChild('dynamicTemplate', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicTemplate!: ViewContainerRef;
      private components: ComponentRef<DynamicSelectedComponent>[] = [];
      private templateComponent: Type<DynamicSelectedComponent> = DynamicSelectedComponent;
    
      action: string;
      local_data: any;
      openDynamicComponent: boolean = false;
      public showcomment: boolean = true;
    
      constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogGridActionComponent>,
        @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DataGridModel,
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    
        this.local_data = { ...data };
        this.action = this.local_data.action;
      }
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    
      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.templateComponent);
        let component = this.dynamicTemplate.createComponent(componentFactory);
        component.instance._ref = component;
        this.components = this.components.concat(component);
    
        }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ng-template #dynamicTemplate></ng-template>
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createComponent')
    at DialogGridActionComponent.ngAfterViewInit (dialog-grid-action.component.ts:36:26)
```